# Strictly monotone real function: stationary point, non-differentiable point

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If we have a real function $f$ that is strictly increasing (or strictly decreasing), what can we say about measure and cardinality of stationary points/points with no derivative.

In particular:

-Is the set of stationary point countable? Measure zero?

-Is the set of point where derivative does not exist countable? Measure zero?

-If it have derivative everywhere (but not necessary continuous derivative) what can we say about its set of stationary point?

What I have so far:

-Derivative does not exist due to discontinuity is accounted for, only countable of them.

-Inverse always exist and is also monotone, and stationary point of $f$ corresponde to point with no derivative of $f^{-1}$, so if we solve the 2nd one we might be done with first one, or perhaps the other way round, depend on what the answer is.

-I am thinking of tweaking Cantor's staircase to make it strictly increasing, while still have stationary point almost everywhere. But cannot figure out how. The main problem is that I do not know anything about the derivative of a function even if I know those of functions that converge uniformly to it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is the set of stationary point countable? Measure zero?

It can have positive measure. Let $K\subset [0,1]$ be a [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set), and define $$f(x)=\int_0^x (\operatorname{dist}(t,K))^2\,dt \tag{1}$$ 
 This function is strictly increasing, since $K$ is nowhere dense. It is differentiable with continuous derivative which vanishes at every point of $K$. So this answers your third question too.

The inverse $f^{-1}$ is not differentiable on $f(K)$; however  a result stated below implies that   $f(K)$ has measure zero.

- Is the set of point where derivative does not exist countable? Measure zero?

It need not be countable (take [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) $+x$), but it [has measure zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#Some_basic_applications_and_results), by a theorem of Lebesgue.

---

Aside: with a bit of machinery, (1) can be improved. It is known that for every closed set (in particular for $K$) there exists a $C^\infty $ smooth function  $g$ that vanishes precisely on that set. An antiderivative of $g^2$ is $C^\infty$ smooth, and has zero derivative everywhere on $K$.

Comment: I am still trying to digest it, need more machinary than what I learnt. I have questions: what is "affine"? and it seems like there is something wrong with my argument from what you said, but I can't figure this out: so what if we take one of the function with positive measure stationary point, inverse it to get a monotone function but now stationary point become points with no derivative, then what happened to those positive measure? Thanks.

Comment: @Humanoid Affine means a function of the form $ax+b$; some people call these "linear".  For the second point: what happens is that $C$, the set of stationary points, has positive measure, but $f'(C)$ has measure zero. A strictly increasing function can send sets of positive measure into sets of zero measure, and vice versa.

Comment: So $f$ is guaranteed to be differentiable everywhere (not just almost everywhere) in $K$? Since your answer to the question that require everywhere differentiable only involve fixing $f$ on the complement of $K$? Sorry if I miss out something obvious, I just have not learn of Lebesgue's density theorem, and the page does not seems to claim that density always exist.

Comment: @Humanoid Yes, I think that the first version of $f$ is differentiable everywhere except the endpoints of removed intervals; all other points of $K$ are the points of density of $K$, hence $f'=0$ there. At the endpoints of removed intervals we have a corner, but changing $f$ as in the second to last paragraph corrects that.

Comment: Ah sorry, but I have not been able to figure out how point of density of fat Cantor set include all point that is not at end point of removed interval. Can you give some hints?

Comment: @Humanoid I rewrote  the answer, replacing the example with a simpler and better one. (You should not mark an answer as accepted until it actually settles the question you asked.)

Comment: @user127096: The function $f$ is defined from $[0,1]$ and since $f^{'}(x)=0$ for all $x\in K$, then can $f$ be strictly increasing?